# Date compare condition not working in Entity Framework 5 query - Code First - DB2 database

Tags: .net, db2, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 to connect to a DB2 database (code first).

I'm attempting to perform a simple comparison between two dates as a condition for my WHERE clause:

```
        using (MEW_Context context = new DataAccess.MEW_Context())
        {
            var query = context.MIList.AsQueryable();

            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime lastSunday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);

            query = query.Where(i => lastSunday != today && lastSunday <= i.ScheduleDate);
        }
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
Extent1.ITEM_NO AS ITEM_NO
FROM TESTDB2.VLS_MISS_INST_SUM AS Extent1
WHERE (@p__linq__0 <> @p__linq__1) AND (@p__linq__2 <= Extent1.SCH_DATE)
```

I receive the following error:

**InnerException = {"ERROR [42609] [IBM][DB2] SQL0417N  A statement string to be prepared contains parameter markers as the operands of the same operator."}**

I also noticed that the generated SQL did not wrap the condition properly as a singular statement to be evaluated.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can get this date compare condition to work? Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: DB2 needs to know the data types to compare. `@p__linq__0 <> @p__linq__1` does not give it any information about that. I don't know enough about the entity framework to tell you what to do about it. In the SQL statement you would use an explicit `CAST` for at least one of the operands, better for both: `...WHERE (CAST(@p__linq__0 AS DATE) <> CAST(@p__linq__1 AS DATE))... `

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve by

```
lastSunday != 1-1-0001
```

because that is what is does.

It's enough to do the second comparison only because `lastSunday` will never be more than 7 days ago and it will always have a value.

Apparently, the DB2 query provider doesn't allow an operand to operate on two external variables, only on database columns and variables.

Comment: The nothing date variable is just a placeholder...I simply want to compare two dates and do something if they aren't equal.

Comment: Well, if `lastSunday == today` you don't even have to execute the query.